# MySQL to update a table with information from another table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I can only explain this with an example.

I have 2 tables (`table1` and `table2`) which each contain `fielda` `fieldb` `fieldc` and `fieldd`.

I want to

```
UPDATE table2 
SET    table2.fieldc = table1.fieldc, 
       table2.fieldd = table1.fieldd 
WHERE  table2.fielda = table1.fielda 
       AND table2.fieldb = table1.fieldb
```

Comment: This can be accomplished using a `JOIN`

Comment: Have you actually named the tables `tableX` and the columns `fieldX`?

Comment: Whats wrong with that? Just kidding, of course not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just miss "table1" declaration

```
update table2, table1
...
```

other version

```
UPDATE table2
JOIN table1 
  ON table2.fielda = table1.fielda 
       AND table2.fieldb = table1.fieldb 
SET    table2.fieldc = table1.fieldc, 
       table2.fieldd = table1.fieldd
```

Comment: @hek2mgl no, that's what we want, isn'tit ?

Comment: I don't like the answer (prefer `JOIN`) but it is correct. The `table1` will not be updated.

Comment: @hek2mgl: What is wrong, have you tried it? And why meaningless, it says "change the first line of the query to this" ...

Comment: @all.. It's ok.. I where (totally) wrong.. Btw. I would prefer the join solution